# why isn't $cI_2$ diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

A question in my linear algebra textbook asks me to prove that $cI_2$ is not diagonalizable. Since an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, we know that $cI_2$ is not diagonalizable. However, using a different approach, I reached the opposite conclusion and can't figure out where I went wrong.

By definition, a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if $P^{-1}AP = D$, and $D$ is diagonal. So,

$$\begin{align}
D & = P^{-1}AP \\
& = P^{-1}(cI_2)P \\
& = c(P^{-1}IP)\\
& = c(P^{-1}P)\\
& = cI
\end{align}$$

Since $cI$ is diagonal, $D$ is diagonal, and $cI$ is therefore diagonalizable. A similar approach I thought of is to let $P=I$ so that

$$\begin{align}
D & = P^{-1}(cI_2)P \\
& = c(I^{-1}II)\\
& = cI^3\\
& = cI
\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you sure the notation $I_2$ refers to an identity matrix?

Comment: @Hurkyl I believe the convention is that $I_2$ refers to the $2\times2$ identity matrix. However, in the book they actually just draw the matrix.

Comment: @MattMunson What kinda of textbook is this? Throw it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. I is diagonalizable, and all diagonal matrices are (almost) by definition diagonalizable since one may choose (as you do), $P=I$.

(I am currently teaching in a Linear algebra course).

Comment: Ok, awesome. It seems the text mistakenly concludes that $cI$ does not have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, well ,there's your error then, since clearly, EVERY vector is an eigenvector of cI.